# jstree plugin will not refresh the tree after ajax insertion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jstree

I tried to use jsTree the first time. I managed to build the tree from json that I got from my server. I can even save my data through an ajax call, but after it I can not make the tree to refresh no matter what I try. If I hit f5 it loads the new children normally.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function refresh_tree() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>' + '/index.php/category/generateTree',
                success: function(categories) {
                    $('#jstree').jstree({
                        'core' : {
                            'data': jQuery.parseJSON(categories),
                            'multiple' : false
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }

        $('#submit_button').click(function(button){
            button.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>' + '/index.php/category/add',
                    data:{cat_name: $('#name').val(), cat_desc: $('#description').val(), cat_parent: $('#parent').val()},
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(){
                        refresh_tree();
                    }
                })
        })

        refresh_tree();

    });
</script>
```

I have tried a lot of different refresh functions aswell like:

```
$.jstree.reference("#jstree").refresh();
$("#jstree").jstree("refresh");
$.jstree._reference('#jstree').jstree.refresh();
```

I have tried to put these codes after the top ajax call and in the success part of the bottom ajax call, but nothing happens. The first ajax call gets the correct updated json after I add a new element but it wont get displayed no matter what.

Comment: try `$.jstree._reference('#jstree').refresh();`

Comment: I have tried this one aswell, but it says:

TypeError: $.jstree._reference is not a function:
$.jstree._reference('#jstree').refresh();

Comment: please check if the issue that does not work is from the jstree version, cuz the latest version has another similar like this:  $.jstree.reference('#jstree').refresh();